# Chrome extension initiate browser_action popup from background scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to show a chrome extension popup from a trigger to shortcut keys like(ctrl+shift+U).

Manifest Json:

```
 "commands": {

    "generate_link": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+K",
        "mac": "Command+K"
      },
      "description": "Builds link copy to extension."
    },


    "show-interface": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+K",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+K"
      },
      "description": "Show builder interface2."
    }
```

Background script:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {

    chrome.tabs.update({}, function(tab) {
    if (command == 'generate_link')
    {
       //need to show extension window with some info about the current tab
        getLink(tablink)
    }
    else if (command == 'show-interface')
          alert('show-interface');
  });
});
```

Is there any function that could trigger the same task that happens when we click on browser_action icon.

This could be simple but new to chrome extensions and terminology, didn't find any good references for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"global": true`. Here's a reference for chrome commands: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands

Comment: commands are working and I am able to run my scripts. My question is,  do we have any option to open extension popup from background script.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found it, this in command section is used to trigger the chrome extension open from shortcut.

```
"_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+K",
        "mac": "Command+Shift+K"
      }
```

It was a misunderstanding of terminologies. 
Thanks.